# Using the predict() function to make predictions past your existing data

Tags: r, predict

I have a series of algorithms I am running on financial data.   For the purposes of this question I have financial market data for a stock with 1226 rows of data.

```
I run the follow code to fit and predict the model:

strat.fit <- glm(DirNDay ~l_UUP.Close + l_FXE.Close + MA50 + +MA10 + RSI06 + BIAS10 + BBands05, data=STCK.df,family="binomial") 
strat.probs <- predict(strat.fit, STCK.df,type="response")
```

I get probability prediction up to row 1226,  I am interested in making a prediction for a new day which would be 1227.  I get the following response on an attempt for a predict on day 1227

> strat.probs[1227]
>           
>           NA

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: The way `predict` works is you give the function the `glm` object, plus new Xs and it gives you predicted Ys.

Comment: how is what you described different than what I did?   The way this works is I get the end of day data and then run the data and it outputs a probability, the probability I am looking for is for the next day

Answer (score 2):

The `predict` function is going to predict the value of DirNDay based on the value of the other variables *for that day*. If you want it to predict DirNDay for a new day, then you need to provide it with all the other relevant variables for that new day.

It sounds like that's not what you're trying to do, and you need to create a totally different model which uses time (or day) to predict the values. Then you can provide `predict` with a new time and it can use that to predict a new DirNDay.

There's a free online textbook about forecasting using R by Rob Hyndman if you don't know where to start: https://www.otexts.org/fpp

(But if I totally misunderstood that glm model then nevermind those last two paragraphs.)

Comment: Thanks, You right on as of what I am trying to do, I have daily updates of data (end of day data) and a very well functioning backtest.  The forecast functions you referenced in the texts are for time series and typically ARIMA models(which I am not using now).  I have about 11 different algorithms (primarily regression and decision trees) that I am running a predict function on.   I need to figure how to translate these models forward.  Collectively they predict current day very well.  I will not have the new days data at the time of prediction.

Comment: If you have data for sequential days, why not treat it as a time series? Or, let's back up. So you don't have any data about tomorrow, but somehow you think this model should be able to tell you about tomorrow. How? What parts of the data that you have today are supposed to help forecast the results tomorrow? When you answer that question, you can create a new model that uses older data to predict newer outcomes, and that's what you're looking for.

Comment: The simplest thing you could do with this data is run the regression with all the variables from day t and use them to predict DirNDay for day t+1. Add another column to your data frame which is DirNDay, but shifted ahead by one day and run the regression on that new column. Then you can plug your last row of numbers into `predict` to get a prediction for tomorrow. But you could probably improve a lot on that prediction with more complicated forecasting techniques.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make a prediction for the 1228th day, you'll need to know what the values of your explanatory variables (MA50, MA10, etc) will be for the 1228th day.  Store those as a new data frame (say STCK.df.new) and put that into your predict function:

```
STCK.df.new <- data.frame(l_UUP.Close = .4, l_FXE.Close = 2, ... )
strat.probs <- predict(strat.fit ,STCK.df.new ,type="response")
```